# How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?

Tags: php, subdomain

How do I create subdomain like `http://user.mywebsite.example`? Do I have to access `.htaccess` somehow? Is it actually simply possible to create it via pure PHP code or I need to use some external script-server side language?

To those who answered: Well, then, should I ask my hosting if they provide some sort of DNS access?

Comment: Perhaps its not required to ask your provider for DNS access, since subdomain routing (answer of Mark) already activated! Just try in your browser if subdomains give you a result. And then route them with the .htaccess file.

Comment: If you can use `wildcard subdomains` this can be achieved in `.htaccess`. See my solution.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You're looking to create a custom **A record**.

I'm pretty sure that you can use wildcards when specifying A records which would let you do something like this:

```
*.mywebsite.example       IN  A       127.0.0.1
```

*`127.0.0.1` would be the IP address of your webserver. The method of actually adding the record will depend on your host.*

---

Then you need to configure your web-server to serve all subdomains.

- Nginx: `server_name .mywebsite.example`
- Apache: `ServerAlias *.mywebsite.example`

Regarding .htaccess, you don't really need any rewrite rules. The `HTTP_HOST` header is available in PHP as well, so you can get it already, like

```
$username = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ".");
```

---

If you don't have access to DNS/web-server config, doing it like `http://mywebsite.example/user` would be a lot easier to set up if it's an option.

Comment: Unless each subdomain is served off of a different server, I would thing creating Canonical Name (CNAME) records would be a better plan.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

Comment: The subdomain does look nice.  It's going to be a lot more work to set up though because you'll have to make sure that all subdomain requests get handled properly.  This isn't terrible with Apache but might be tricky in a hosted environment.

Comment: @theraccoonbear  Assuming you can use wildcards with CNAME as well, that's a thought.

Comment: Does it actually mean that PHP code would have to add a new Rewriterule to htacccess only?

Comment: If you get the DNS and rewrite rules set up properly, you'll just be passing whatever the current username is into PHP as a GET variable.  Then you can handle it from there however you want.

Comment: PHP shouldn't have to worry about adding anything.  It just deals with what gets fed to it.

Comment: Mark, I tried to put that "http://mywebsite.com/user into .htaccess however the website did not display. I guess something went wrong with hosting ^^ Some "IIS Password" problem.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  .htaccess is for Apache, not IIS.  I'm not sure how url rewriting is handled with IIS but I believe there have been some questions about there on SO.

Comment: hi mark, I followed the steps you gave above but the when I do http://xyz.mydomain.com it redirects to http://xyz.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi... Do I need to do anything else then steps mentioned above ?

Comment: Hi Mark, I think the problem is due to the IP address as I have a shared hosting... So is there any solution to this situation

Comment: Ashish, I think your best bet is to post a new question on http://serverfault.com/ with the specifics of your configuration.

Comment: I'm used the above code, its worked for me. But when i put www.domain.com its treating www also a sub domain. Can u revise your code ?

Comment: @MarkBiek:Do we need to write other things in htaccess file e.g Mod rewrite ON and other things or simply the logic explained above can work? sorry for lack of knowledge here i dont know much about HTACCESS

Comment: @noobie-php, yes you'd need mod_rewrite and AllowOverride set for your webroot (so you can have a .htaccess file). There are lots of good Apache/htaccess tutorials out there explaining that stuff in more detail.

Comment: Is possible do this in a web app with CodeIgniter?

Comment: How to add A RECORD on ubuntu Im using LEMP server? Thanks God Bless sir really need your help

Comment: @GoperLeoZosa, You'll probably have more luck asking that question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See my solution. I have it working perfectly just using `.htaccess` and a `wildcard subdomain`.

Comment: @MarkBiek Tumblr making the profile urls like this ? If yes please answer my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011867/how-to-make-a-tumblr-style-profile-url

Answer (score 35):

The feature you are after is called [Wildcard Subdomains](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wildcard+subdomains). It allows you not have to setup DNS for each subdomain, and instead use Apache rewrites for the redirection. You can find a nice tutorial [here](http://steinsoft.net/static/archive/2014/steinsoft.net/index5d37.html?site=Programming/Articles/apachewildcarddomain), but there are thousands of tutorials out there. Here is the necessary code from that tutorial:

```
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.55>
    DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
    ServerName www.domain.example
    ServerAlias *.domain.example
</VirtualHost>
```

However as it required the use of VirtualHosts it must be set in the server's `httpd.conf` file, instead of a local `.htaccess`.

Comment: i can not reach httpd.conf file since i am on shared hosting. what can i do?

Answer (score 22):

I do it a little different from Mark. I pass the entire domain and grab the subdomain in PHP.

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1&hostName=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

This ignores images and maps everything else to my `index.php` file. So if I go to

```
http://fred.mywebsite.example/album/Dance/now
```

I get back

```
http://fred.mywebsite.example/index.php?uri=album/Dance/now&hostName=fred.mywebsite.example
```

Then in my `index.php` code I just explode my username off of the hostName. This gives me nice pretty SEO URLs.

Answer (score 16):

We setup wildcard DNS like they explained above. So the a record is `*.yourname.example`

Then all of the subdomains are actually going to the same place, but PHP treats each subdomain as a different account.

We use the following code:

```
$url=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$account=str_replace(".yourdomain.com","",$url);
```

This code just sets the `$account` variable the same as the subdomain. You could then retrieve their files and other information based on their account.

This probably isn't as efficient as the ways they list above, but if you don't have access to BIND and/or limited `.htaccess` this method should work (as long as your host will setup the wildcard for you).

We actually use this method to connect to the customers database for a multi-company e-commerce application, but it may work for you as well.

Comment: I think this sould be currect answer , As op ask about how **PHP** handle subdmoins NOT How web or  DNS  **Servers** handel subdomains .

Answer (score 8):

Don't fuss around with `.htaccess` files when you can use [Apache mass virtual hosting][1].

From the documentation:

> `#include part of the server name in the filenames VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%2/docs`

In a way it's the reverse of your question: every 'subdomain' is a user. If the user does not exist, you get an 404.

The only drawback is that the environment variable `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is not correctly set to the *used* subdirectory, but the default document_root in de htconfig.
[1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: I am not really sure how to use that.. and in the end, why not to mess up with htaccess?

Answer (score 6):

Simple PHP solution for subdomains and multi-domain web apps

Step 1. Provide DNS A record as "*" for domains (or domain) you gonna serve `example.org`

```
A record => *.example.org
A record => *.example.net
```

Step 2. Check uniquity of logins when user registering or changing login.
Also, avoid dots in those logins.

Step 3. Then check the query
<?php

```
        // Request was http://qwerty.example.org
        $q = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        /*
            We get following array
            Array
            (
                [0] => qwerty
                [1] => example
                [2] => org
            )
        */

        // Step 4.
        // If second piece of array exists, request was for
        // SUBDOMAIN which is stored in zero-piece $q[0]
        // otherwise it was for DOMAIN

        if(isset($q[2])) {
            // Find stuff in database for login $q[0] or here it is "qwerty"
            // Use $q[1] to check which domain is asked if u serve multiple domains
        }

?>
```

This solution may serve different domains

```
qwerty.example.org
qwerty.example.net

johnsmith.somecompany.example
paulsmith.somecompany.example
```

If you need same nicks on different domains served differently,
you may need to store user choise for domain when registering login.

```
smith.example.org // Show info about John Smith
smith.example.net // Show info about Paul Smith
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to configuration changes on your WWW server to handle the new subdomain, your code would need to be making changes to your DNS records.  So, unless you're running your own BIND (or similar), you'll need to figure out how to access your name server provider's configuration.  If they don't offer some sort of API, this might get tricky.

Update: yes, I would check with your registrar if they're also providing the name server service (as is often the case).  I've never explored this option before but I suspect most of the consumer registrars do not.  I Googled for GoDaddy APIs and GoDaddy DNS APIs but wasn't able to turn anything up, so I guess the best option would be to check out the online help with your provider, and if that doesn't answer the question, get a hold of their support staff.

Answer (score 3):

You could [potentially] do a rewrite of the URL, but yes: you have to have control of your DNS settings so that when a user is added it gets its own subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in `.htaccess` provided your server is configured to allow wildcard subdomains. I achieved that in JustHost by creating a subomain manually named `*` and specifying a folder called subdomains as the document root for wildcard subdomains. Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.example$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.website\.example$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA]
```

Finally, create a folder for your subdomain and place the subdomains files.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add, that if you use CloudFlare (free), you can use their API to manage your dns with ease.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can accomplish this via two steps.

1. Setup wildcard subdomain
2. Get the subdomain entered by user
3. Validate the subdomain

---

#### 1. Setup wildcard subdomain

This might vary depending on your hosting provider. I use Namecheap.com, and the process was as simple as follows
[image: creating a sub domain in namecheap]

- go to cPanel
- go to sub domains
- enter "*" as the value of subdomain

Now every time you enter a random string before your domain name, it will direct to the wildcard sub domain. You can modify the contents of this wildcard subdomain.

#### 2. Get the subdomain entered by user

You can now add a php file in the wildcard directory in file manager.

```
<?php
    
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
  <head>
      
    <title>Wildcard Subdomain</title>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <h1>The visitor went to 
      <?php 
        
        echo "<br>";
        
        print("link is: ".$link);
        
        print("<br><br>");
        
        echo "actual file: ".$actual_link;
      ?> 
      </h1>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

#### 3. Validate the subdomain

You might want to validate the sub domain to check if there is some user linked to it. This can be done with a check to a database.

Comment: Actually, the second step is to configure the web-server

Answer (score 0):

> Create Dynamic Subdomains using PHP and `.htaccess`

#(1) Root `.htaccess`
This file is redirection `http://www.yourwebsite.example` to `http://yourwebsite.example` for home page use. All of the subdomain redirection to yourwebsite_folder

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourwebsite.example
RewriteRule (.*) http://yourwebsite.example/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite\.example $
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.yourwebsite.example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourwebsite_folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /yourwebsite_folder/$1
```

#(2) Inside Folder `.htaccess`
This file is rewriting the subdomain URLs.

`http://yourwebsite.example/index.php?siteName=9lessons`
to
`http://9lessons.yourwebsite.example`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?siteName=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.yourwebsite.example
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?siteName=%1
```

More `.htaccess` tips: [Htaccess File Tutorial and Tips.](https://www.9lessons.info/2013/11/htaccess-file-tutorial-and-tips.html)

#index.php
This file contains simple PHP code, using regular expressions validating the subdomain value.

```
<?php
$siteName='';
if($_GET['siteName'] )
{
$sitePostName=$_GET['siteName'];
$siteNameCheck = preg_match('~^[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,20}$~i', $sitePostName);
   if($siteNameCheck)
   {
     //Do something. Eg: Connect database and validate the siteName.
   }
   else
  {
    header("Location: http://yourwebsite.example/404.php");
   }
}
?>
//HTML Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if($siteNameCheck) { ?>
//Home Page
<?php } else { ?>
//Redirect to Subdomain Page.
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

#No Subdomain Folder
If you are using root directory(htdocs/public_html) as a project directory, use this following `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourwebsite.example
RewriteRule (.*) http://yourwebsite.example/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ index.php?siteName=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.yourwebsite.example
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?siteName=%1
```