# How to create sub-links for user on sign up?

Tags: php, dns, wildcard, hyperlink, wildcard-subdomain

I am looking to create vanity url for my users.  How can i do it?

I want something like username.domain.com

My second question is, can i also customize this upon client requests? Like let's say, Client says add a feature to my account, will I be able to do it since it's almost like a separate site within my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use URL rewriting e.g. via Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to solve this.

For security and practical reasons however, I do not recommend using something like `username.domain.com` unless you carefully filter out user names like `www`.
Better use `username.u.domain.com` or something similar.

Here an example for rewrite rules using HTTP redirection.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.u\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/user/%1 [R,L]
```

Alternatively, you could also use a DNS wildcard / catch-all entry and extract the user name part before your domain using a regular expression, e.g.

```
function getUserNameFromHost() {
    if ( !preg_match('`^(\w+)\.u\.domain\.com$`', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $matches) )
        return false;
    else
        return $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this:

[How to create sub.domain for user opon sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655139/how-to-create-sub-domain-for-user-opon-sign-up)

Comment: I don't understand it.  If you create a sub.link is that almost like having a separate website that you can add features to??

Comment: thing is you have all the tools, you need to figure out how to use them best for your own situation. If there will be physical differences in the files being served on each subdomain, then you will need to copy your basic set of files into the new user directory when a user signs up. If these changes are like "settings" you can save these variations to the database and make the adjustments to pages based on user settings and you wont have to create a separate directory for each user.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite. Use mod_rewrite to display a subdomain in the address bar, but retrieve a different URL internally.

eg: aaa.domain.com  should go to domain.com/users/aaa

Comment: although My answer is right, User: Archimedix above with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807833/how-to-create-sub-links-for-user-on-sign-up/3807899#3807899 deserves the "check", not this one, Can you change it please ?