# using subdomains for user profile urls using php?

Tags: php, subdomain

i was wondering how i can get users to sign up and assign them a subdomain i.e. http://username.tumblr.com  like tumblr and blogger, and why do they use subdomains, and not blogger.com/username, easy urls, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to create a [wildcard dns entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)).
2. There are a couple reason why someone might do this.

   1. It's a different domain so search engines see it as a different website and assign it its own pagerank/value.
   2. it looks "nicer" and feels more personalized to the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. wildcard (*) subdomains
2. because username.service.tdl is more
   "individual" then
   service.tdl/username

for an example with symfony read [Advanced-Routing](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing)