# PHP communicate with other domain

Tags: php

this PHP file is working but now i need a favor one understanding idea.
Domain A and Domain B is in different server.
So now this index.php is in Domain A. I want the following code to generate a link for Domain B and register a domain so it could redirect .
Is it possible?

```
 <?php       
    $new_link = ""; 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['cid'],$_POST['gid']))
        {
            $cid = $_POST['cid'];
            $gid = $_POST['gid'];
            $new_link = "www.something.com/".$cid.$gid;

               // if your input is integer and you want to add them then use this
               // $new_link = "www.something.com/".($cid+$gid);

        }
    }

    ?>


    <form method="post" action="">
         <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 1:</h1>
            <input type="text" value="" name ="cid" id="cid" />
         <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter ID 2:</h1>
            <input type="text" value="" name ="gid" id="gid"/>

        <h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Copy Your Link     Here</h1>
            <textarea style="width:500px; height:50px;"><?php echo $new_link;?></textarea><br /><br /><br />

       <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: elaborate on 'register a domain'. do you mean going to a domain?

Comment: Registering a domain at a "registrar" normally takes some more than simply querying the url. In case you want to link to another server, this should work fine.

Comment: @kennypu , creating a sub domain with affiliate link[Domain B] and the generator for the Domain B is [Domain A]

Comment: @CommuSoft, how to link to the server and enable it to create subdomain.

Comment: if you actually want to create a sub domain, it'll be much work than just using PHP

Comment: @kennypu, i need to play with htaccess also but i just need idea or some help would be appreciated.

Comment: At the very least you need a Wildcard DNS to dynamically create subdomains without needing to modify zone files and vhost files.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, please shine some light . I would wish to know how to solve this issue . haha

Comment: a simple google search pulls this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822117/how-to-dynamically-create-subdomains

Comment: @kennypu , i also got it but then i need Domain A to give permission to Domain B to create a subdomain at Domain B.

Comment: Then that is up to your script. You need to figure out how you're going to identify when it's Domain A and when it's Domain B and how to share permissions across those domains. This is something you must develop.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , for once i'm going to shout your name for my case.