# how to create multiple sub domain in local host?

Tags: php, nginx, dns, subdomain, ubuntu-12.04

Using nginx and php I need to create multiple sub domain in local host. How i can make  it happen?

I am using `ubuntu 12.04` and `php5` with`nginx` as webserver.

i Have tried `*.servername.com` in my configuration file. BUt it is not working.

Comment: This question isn't a program trouble...

Comment: @Marta Fernandeaz thanks alot for ur reply. I know it is not a program related doubt. I am new in this field and need to get a solution. I have searched alot. but

Comment: @thomaschacko try with my answer if find any difficulty let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In localhost you can make entry of subdomain in "hosts" file at dir of C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc (it may be at /etc of linux)

```
127.0.0.1       maindomain.com
127.0.0.1       one.maindomain.com
127.0.0.1       two.maindomain.com
```

After that you have to make entry in httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

DocumentRoot pathToMainDomain
ServerName maindomain.com
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

DocumentRoot pathToMainDomain

ServerName one.maindomain.com
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>

DocumentRoot pathToMainDomain
ServerName two.maindomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hi @prashant M thanks alot for your reply. I this is to create multiple virtual hosts. But in my casse it is not the exact thing which I am looking for. `Dynamically creating sub domain` that is what i needed. Anyways **thanks alot.**

Comment: Always welcome..i will check with Dynamically creating sub domain and update you..Thanks

Comment: hope to hear from u soon.

Comment: Please check with this post i have found related to your query..it may help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822117/how-to-dynamically-create-subdomains   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: i am trying to find exact and clear solution for your query..will keep you update on same.

Comment: if you want I can clarify my question. say a user signed up in my site(`example.com`) and creates a micro site as he wishes say `user1` is his name then the micro site name would created as `user1.example.com` and it should happen dynamically. Since creating virtual host again and again is not practical, I am following this way. please help