# How can i add subdomain based views

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Hello Everyone!**

Currently i'm working on a proyect where every customer can add it's store to add some services and stuff. Even when the view it's the same for all stores (obviously loading each store own data) i would like to create an url using as subdomain the store name like this.

Let's say the store name is : **The Wolf**

So the URL i would like it to have is : ***thewolf.mycustomdomain.com***

I'm currently working on React js using react-router-dom so i would like to ask to this community if anyone knows how to make this happen.

**Thanks in advance if anyone can give me some hints!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create subdomains in react. You need to configure a proxy for it. You can look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822117/how-to-dynamically-create-subdomains) for more information.