# How to create a subdomain with username as subdomain name?

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have referred other related question but they are not clear to me. Please explain me: How can I make subdomain in PHP?

Example :

```
http://www.domainname.com/page.php?usname=sundar
```

I want change the link to this

```
http://sundar.domainname.com
```

Is this possible in PHP? Or any other way to do it?

Comment: this is handled by the server (i.e. apache) not php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)

Answer (score 6):

You may create a virtual sub domains and then you can redirect it with .htaccess.

You also have to create

> **A Record** look like this
>
> ***.exmple.com       A       127.0.0.1 or your IP**

in your DNS.

Then add something like this in your **.htaccess**

> RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$  home.php?username=$1
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*).mywebsite.com
>
> RewriteRule (.*) home.php?username=%1

It should help

Answer (score 3):

my way:
you will have to create a wildcard subdomain and point it you your domain.

http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains

Then you can parse `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for querying out the user name .

if you are under hosting plane, you can probably create it from the GUI.
Else, you need to via the APACHE panel and configure the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .htaccess url rewrite to make that.

Just rewrite www.(username).site.com to www.site.com/profile/(username)

the code for that would be something like..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).site.nl site.nl/profile/$1
```

if my memory serves me right

Comment: Sorry -- it does NOT work like that -- `RewriteRule` only works with path part of the URL. To work with other parts (domain name, port, query string) use `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Yeah that does sound better, my bad, I was typing from memory,