# Creating a Dynamic site where a user is allowed to register and Create more contents with the Same Engine

Tags: php, mysql, html

When I see wordpress.com I was wonder how to Create a Dynamic site like this, where multiple users are allowed to create account and each user will be having the same interface just like in wordpress.com. for me mysite.com/username.

I have a idea like if a user is created then i will create a folder with the same username and copy the whole script inside his account.

But i know wordpress is not like this, they have one wordpress engine. How to create like this I mean idea about programming. I know PHP, mysql and HTML. and I have already created a site where a user is allowed to upload image and view it. But i user on different subdomain or different page mapping with the same engine.

Thanks

Comment: Google "Pretty URLs". There's no copying of folders going on, it's all handled by one script that handles different URLs. URL != folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's never true that for each user script is copied with folder name same as user-name, until it's small and static site.

Here Every thing is controlled with database and sql queries.

PHP and MySQL are two of the most popular open source server-side technologies used to power dynamic websites.

When you create a normal web page with HTML and CSS, all the content is fixed by the webmaster. Everyone who visits the page sees the same content—it's static.

By contrast, the content of a dynamic web page frequently changes in your case according to users. So the page /folder is same for all users but contents are loaded dynamically.

When the web server receives a request, it hands the page to the PHP engine, which normally runs as a module within the server. Depending on the code and type of request, the PHP engine queries the database if necessary, and then builds the HTML output to send back to the browser.

Refer this links for : creating subdomain according to user names :

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14236/subdomains-vs-folders-for-multi-account-users-application

[How to create a subdomain with username as subdomain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895657/how-to-create-a-subdomain-with-username-as-subdomain-name)

Comment: hi Teez thank you for the answer, Can I have a Tutorial Link on how to do that. Most of the time like in facebook.com/myusername will loads my content and so on

Comment: suppose i have a link like this mysite.com/profile.php?username=username I think this type will work.  and in .htaccess i will edit to redirect like to mysite.com/username. :) thanks i got this idea just now...suggest more if you have :P

Comment: Lot of tutorial are there u just google with "virtual subdomains  username with htaccess"