# how to ceate a fake subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

Is this possible with htaccess

http://domain.com/index.php?u=userone

turn to this?

http://userone.domain.com

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895657/how-to-create-a-subdomain-with-username-as-subdomain-name?rq=1 and a couple others. Please use the search function before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need .htaccess for the dynamic subdomains.
Dunno why everyone are so stick with it.
As soon as you will get all *.example.com requests directed to your document root, you will be able to distinguish them using `HTTP_HOST` env variable.

What you really need is to set up your DNS record. And no .htaccess could help you with it.