# subdomains with only .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

i got url link region ex. http://mysite.it/index.php?page=search&sRegion=Toscana

is possible make with htaccess an url like toscana.mysite.it
Thank for answers

This is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.it$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sRegion=([^&]*) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%2.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess : Rewriting initial output back into subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430237/htaccess-rewriting-initial-output-back-into-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.it$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sRegion=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%2.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Ah sorry there was a typo in my answer. Fixed it, try edited code now.

Comment: I tried it and works, but I am redirected to mysite.it, so the dns is ok, but the query is not executed, what's missing?

Comment: Thank anubhava for the answer, rewrite work, i got sRegion.mysite.it/index.php?page=search&sRegion=Toscana, but i get this error "The web page has a redirect loop" and blank page.

My htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ohpla\.it$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)sRegion=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%2.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I hope you can help me, I really need, I'm beating my head from all sides

Comment: I can't read your code from comments, please post this code by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks. Aren't you getting `http://Toscana.mysite.it/index.php?page=search&sRegion=Toscana` URL in your browser when you enter `http://Toscana.mysite.it/index.php?page=search&sRegion=Toscana`

Comment: yes, but page is blank, no take the function of the original page