# Simple way to create subdomains on the fly with PHP

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I would like to know how to set up an automatic & light PHP creating subdomains for each users in my database ?
Is that possible ?

Comment: are you sure you need a real subdomain or url like `mydomain.com/user1234`? Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: If you know how to set up vhosts on Apache then it should be fairly trivial to write scripts to do this for you that can be run using the PHP exec function.

Comment: @redreggae Yes i need a real subdomain like johndoe.mydomain.com :/

Comment: @MarcDelalonde a wildcard dns entry could be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$domainName = 'example.com';
    $subDomainName =  'demo';
     $subDomain = $subDomainName;
    $cPanelUser = 'cpanel_user_name';
    $cPanelPass = 'cpanel_pass';
    $rootDomain = $domainName;
    
    $buildRequest = "/frontend/paper_lantern/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/$domainName/$subDomain";
      
    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
    }
    
    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";
    
    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
    }
    fclose($openSocket);
     
    echo $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ya sure its possible go to http://vikku.info/programming/php/create-subdomain-dynamically-in-php-code-to-create-subdomains-in-server-using-php.htm
or http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17134.html

just configure the setting like add subdomain name ,cpanel username,cpanel password,domail name.it will work.

for example

if your sub domain name is test.example.com

create_subdomain("test","CPANEL_USERNAME","CPANEL_PASSWORD","example.com");