# How to create subdomain dynamically

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, cpanel

I am trying to create url like subdomain without creating subdomain in cpanel.

My current url:

```
http://colleges.com/
```

When it's opened using a mobile device it should become:

```
http://m.colleges.com/
```

Is it possible to do using javascript or jquery?

How to achieve this?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.mysite.com [L,R=301]`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: N.B. You cannot do this in PHP, or JS.

Comment: I have googled for the last 2 days, but didn't find any good details and applied lots of codes. can you please provide me any good link or code snippet.

Comment: Yes is is possible with `JS` even with `PHP`. lacks research i googled "detect mobile in js and php" and the answer was already there

Comment: How to do it in PHP ????

Comment: You could use http://mobiledetect.net/ to perform server-side redirections. Client-side redirections could be done based on a simple regex matching on the user agent. But anyway, you need to first make a mobile version by `http://m.colleges.com/`.

Comment: I want to use same project for both http://m.colleges.com/ and http://colleges.com