# Make URI and Subdomains from CMS based on Symfony

Tags: symfony, uri, subdomain

I need make a CMS based en Symfony and the principal work is create subdomains and URIs... any idea where to start? I working with Symfony but I have not done anything like never ...

Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading about [Symfony2 routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)
Then you have to use an A record in your domain administration pointing every subdomain (wildcards) to an specific ip, and editing your .htaccess in order to get an specific response (based on symfony routes) for your subdomains. [This post can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)