# Create page as subdomain without creating subdomain on server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have URL in my website e.g http://example.com/test and i need this page to be showing as subdomain e.g http://test.example.com/.

i have tried the following things.

I set `redirect 301` rule in htaccess but that is redirecting to homepage 
always.
`Redirect 301 /test http://test.example.com/`

I used few wordpress plugins [wp subdomain revisited](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subdomains-revisited/) and [Main category as subdomain](https://wordpress.org/plugins/main-category-as-subdomain/) but no luck so maybe they are older versions.

I have setup a wildcard subdomain (*.subdomain.com) and the folder is set to public html main root directory.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wilcard subdomain feature at server and htaccess file  http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/subdomains.html

Comment: so isn't it not enough to create a wildcard subdomain(*.example.com) at server?