# nginx rewrite wildcard subdomain to base php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to create a sub domain for each user.So I pointed wildcard subdomain to my server.My server is running with nginx and php-fpm.All subdomains

```
username.site.com/page
```

should rewrite to

```
/index.php?user=username&page=page
```

I am new to nginx so please help me.I already found out , how to do with apache in this link 
[How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)
and please explain it so that I can modify it for my needs.I already tried apache to nginx rewriter , it doesn't works.