# How to create an auto-create subdomain for users that signup on a website?

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain, httpd.conf, user-accounts

When a new user signs up to my site I want a subdomain to be created automatically when they sign up which will contain the some content on my site. Similar to how Quora does their blogs ex: username.mysite.com. I am using wordpress to create my website and I am using Godaddy to host my website. I am not sure about how to this.
What I already done: 
1. I created a wildcard 
2. I all ready setup a subdomain based wordpress multisite/network 
3. All ready configured the wildcard (https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains )

[image]
I made sure to point the wildcard to same folder location where my wp-config.php file is located, but I am not sure what else to do. I create a created a new account on my website and it does not showing http://username.mywebsite.com . What’s the next step to get?

Comment: Try searching here or in google first!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/183971/1097415

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)