# Virtual host or simply rewrite?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I've a website that has a profile page. Obviously all users have an own profile page available on this url: domain.dev/profile?user=%username%.

Now, I want to do that every user can see the profile on username.domain.dev.

I saw many post about that like [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user) but it doesn't resolve my problem.

I've my website on ubuntu (nginx) and also on Windows IIS 10. 
How can I do that? Do you have some other link/question that can I see? Or some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nginx, you just need to set up something similar to this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.dev;
    ...
}
```

Notice the:

```
server_name  *.domain.dev;
```

Within your application, you will need to split/handle the [HOST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) header.

Another approach but this implies a [redirect 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) is to do something like this:

```
server {
   listen      80;
   server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.your-domain\.tld$;
   return 301 https://domain.dev/profile?user=$subdomain;
}
```

In this case, notice the [regex](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) in the server_name:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.your-domain\.tld$;
```

This helps you to use the subdomain as `$subdomain`.

To avoid a redirect this may work:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.your-domain\.tld$;

  location / {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://httpbin.org/get?user=$subdomain;
    proxy_set_header Host httpbin.org; 
  } 
}
```

For testing purposes, I am using http://httpbin.org/`on the`proxy_pass`, so that you could test with something like:

```
$ curl foo.your-domain.tld:8080
{
  "args": {
    "user": "foo"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  }, 
  "origin": "91.65.17.142", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?user=foo"
}
```

Notice the response:

```
"url": "http://httpbin.org/get?user=foo"
```

Matching the subdomain `foo`.your-domain.tld in this case.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but when instead I go to test.domain.dev it redirects to the index page. My problem is to create a rule to rewrite the user profile. Instead: http://test.domain.dev does not have to show the index but test's user profile that is on domain.dev/profile?user=test

Comment: Just add another example to send test.domain.dev to domain.dev/profile?user=test, hope it help

Comment: There is a way to see what I see on /profile?user=test in test.domain.dev? 
 Without a redirect I mean

Comment: I added an example to use `proxy_pass` give a try