# How would custom user links work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

By custom user links, i mean like for example when a user registers to the website, a page is created specifically for that user with a link.

**For Example**

```
https:/domain.com/users/customerName
```

Then after creating the link, the website will automatically customize the website by using a clone of a specific webpage.

*Btw i've already took Care of the Login/Register part. I just need to know how custom user links would work.

Comment: You use a database to hold the data for each user. By creating a custom ID for each user and binding it to a login, when a user goes to his profile page you can use PHP to fetch all the data needed and fill the page with the gathered information.

Comment: Have you ever Seen this ? http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: You could have a PHP script that creates a folder.. but I'm not sure what you mean with a clone of a website. Sounds complicated. Whats the idea?

Comment: This link could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Comment: You might also want to consider using the users *id* or some other generated unique id instead of the users name. Because what do you do when two users have the same name?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: `example.com/user`

Use a single PHP file and an .htaccess file. Check out [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

### Option 2: `user.example.com`

Create sub-domains for each user, also uses .htaccess. Check out [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)

### Option 3: `example.com?user=name`

Create a single php file and use `$_GET` parameters. This is the most usual and easiest way to customize the website based on the user who registered and logged in. (usually using user ID number: `example.com/profile.php?user=71`)

Of course there's also [Session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you searching for **URL rewriting** concept.
If user login the page no need to clone the page.you could access the same page with this user data and specification(dynamic page).Many the page content with php functions

[**URL rewriting**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihhbbf2J3YAhXLuY8KHc7VCl4QFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16388959%2Furl-rewriting-with-php&usg=AOvVaw0nX7q07w-Aru8Vcj39cEFo)

you could the function in .htaccess
if user enters the page

http://example.com/someuser

its rewrite the url with

http://example.com?q=someuser

if you see the url bar its like special page for the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly simple. You just use GET within PHP and the URL would be something like http://example.com/user?id=4453623 - If you've ever been on facebook you'll notice they use PHP for the profile pages and much other things too. If you go to your profile page, you'll notice a "id=" variable up in the URL and that's how they determine which profile page to display to you.

This is basically what @Granny commented.