# How to create sub domain with codeigniter in Cpanel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopify

I want create sub domain with codeigniter like shopify and i don't want to write code in .htacess file,
Example:
https://irfaxexpress.myshopify.com

Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let PHP to create subdomain automatically for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user)